# Karma debug showing empty screen

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-runner

When running tests for angular2 using Karma, when I click the debug button I'm not getting the on screen info that Im expecting, letting me know if the tests have passed etc.

They are passing ok in the console window.

I'm new to all this so would greatly appreciate some help!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I do not exactly know your setup and what you expect to see. But I had a similar problem with the angular starter project from https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter.

The solution for me was to add `"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2"` as dev dependency in `package.json` and `'kjhtml'` as reporter in `config/karma.conf.js`. After running `npm install` and `npm run watch:test` Chrome starts and the tests are executed but the Chrome window keeps open. When I click on "Debug", it shows the tests (an empty list for the starter project). I hope this helps.